# Problems get my Datamodel into a WPF Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I want to create WPF application which should look like [Decksumme Skizze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BfgU.png). You have X participant, who can attend in y discipline. In each discipline they can collect 1 - z scores.

The data model looks like

```
public class ParticipantsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Result> Results { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }
}
public class Participant
{
    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
public class Discipline
{
    public int DisciplineId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

The data binding to the view

```
using (var db = new ParticipantsContext())
{
     var participants = db.Participants.ToList();
     for( int i = 0; i < participants.Count; i++)
     {
       participants[i].Disciplines = participants[i].Disciplines.ToList();
     }
     DecksummeAnzeige.DataContext = participants;
     DecksummeAnzeige.ItemsSource = participants;
}
```

One participant of the participants list looks like [ParticipantObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E21T.png)

I tried severell things but I didn't find a good way to display the disciplines and the related scores. My last thought was to use another DataGrid inside a TemplateColumn. But that shows me Error message in the console.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DecksummeAnzeige" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0" FrozenColumnCount="4" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"  AlternationCount="2">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ParticipantId}" Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Forename}" Header="Vorname" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ergebnisse" IsReadOnly="True">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Disciplines}" HeadersVisibility="None">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DisciplineId}" IsReadOnly="True" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name }" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
          </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Is there a best practice or example somewhere which does similar from which I could learn or does someone has an advice how to manage this?

Comment: What is ParticipantsContext?

Comment: @SamXia added to the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a no header DataGrid in DataGrid column data template:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="DecksummeAnzeige" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0" FrozenColumnCount="4" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"  AlternationCount="2">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ParticipantId}" Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Forename}" Header="Vorname" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ergebnisse" IsReadOnly="True">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <!--here is the changes-->
                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Disciplines}" HeadersVisibility="None">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DisciplineId}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name }" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <!--end here-->
                </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I get an error which I don't understand. `System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Disciplines' value (type 'ICollection\`1') from '' (type 'Participant_3157'). BindingExpression:Path=Disciplines; DataItem='Participant_3157' (HashCode=533144); target element is 'DataGrid'; target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been `

Comment: `disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.get_Connection()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery\`1.GetResults(Nullable\`1 forMergeOption)`

Comment: That is caused by your using block. You binding data for DataGrid is defined in the using block, after that, it will be disposed. It failed because when framework want to find your ItemsSource, its associated context ends.

Comment: could it be that Disciplines is a ICollection and not a List? That I need to convert the ICollection to a List?

Comment: @svanschu That depends on your implementation. ICollection just a declaration of your interface. The instance of Disciplines needs some implementation like List.

Comment: the error disapeared as I added `for( int i = 0; i < participants.Count; i++)
                {
                    participants[i].Disciplines = participants[i].Disciplines.ToList();
                }` What you are meaning with Disciplines needs some implementation like List. You can see the implementation of Disciplines in the above code.

Comment: I think thats why error said (type Participant_3157). The data type you get from DSet possibly does not match the Interface(type ICollection). So you need cast not implementation or instance.

Comment: Where should I cast? How would you do the combination between Entity Framework and WPF?

Comment: @svanschu like what you did.`participants[i].Disciplines = participants[i].Disciplines.ToList(); }` make your **DBSet** cast to **List**

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would set it up, it's not exactly how you would like but, may give you some ideas:
Model Setup:

```
 public sealed class Participant
{
    #region Attributes
    public int _ParticipantId;
    public string _Forename;
    public string _Name;
    public List<Model.Discipline> Disciplines;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public int ParticipantId
    {
        get
        {
            return _ParticipantId;
        }
        set
        {
            _ParticipantId = value;
        }
    }

    public string Forename
    {
        get
        {
            return _Forename;
        }
        set
        {
            _Forename = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public Participant(): base()
    {
        ParticipantId = 0;
        Forename = string.Empty;
        Name = string.Empty;
        Disciplines = null;
    }

    public Participant(DataRow dr) : base()
    {
        InitFromDB(dr);
    }
    #endregion

    public void InitFromDB(DataRow dr)
    {
        if (DBNull.Value != (dr["ParticipantId"]))
            ParticipantId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ParticipantId"]);
        if (DBNull.Value != (dr["Forename"]))
            Forename = Convert.ToString(dr["Forename"]);
        if (DBNull.Value != (dr["Name"]))
            Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]);
    }

}
```

Then The Discipline Model:

```
 public sealed class Discipline
{
    #region Attributes
    public int _DisciplineId;
    public string _Name;
    public int _Result1;
    public int _Result2;
    public int _Result3;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public int DisciplineId
    {
        get
        {
            return _DisciplineId;
        }
        set
        {
            _DisciplineId = value;
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
        }
    }

    public int Result1
    {
        get
        {
            return _Result1;
        }
        set
        {
            _Result1 = value;
        }
    }
    public int Result2
    {
        get
        {
            return _Result2;
        }
        set
        { 
            _Result2 = value;
        }
    }
    public int Result3
    {
        get
        {
            return _Result3;
        }
        set
        {
            _Result3 = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public Discipline() : base()
    {
        DisciplineId = 0;
        Name = string.Empty;
        Result1 = 0;
        Result2 = 0;
        Result3 = 0;
    }

    public Discipline(DataRow dr) : base()
    {
        InitFromDB(dr);
    }
    #endregion

    public void InitFromDB(DataRow dr)
    {
        if (DBNull.Value != (dr["DisciplineId"]))
            DisciplineId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DisciplineId"]);
        if (DBNull.Value != (dr["Name"]))
            Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]);
        if (DBNull.Value != (dr["Result1"]))
            Result1 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Result1"]);
        if (DBNull.Value != (dr["Result2"]))
            Result2 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Result2"]);
        if (DBNull.Value != (dr["Result3"]))
            Result3 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Result3"]);
    }
}
```

Then here's how I would call them:

```
 try
        {
            List<Model.Participant> participants = new List<Model.Participant>();
            DataTable participantDT = new DataTable();
            //participantDT = GetYourParticipantDT;

            foreach (DataRow tmpdr in participantDT.Rows)
            {
                Model.Participant tmpmodel = new Model.Participant(tmpdr);
                List<Model.Discipline> disciplines = new List<Model.Discipline>();

                DataTable disciplineDT = new DataTable();
                // disciplineDT = GetYourDisciplineDT;
                foreach (DataRow dr in disciplineDT.Rows)
                {
                    disciplines.Add(new Model.Discipline(dr));
                }

                tmpmodel.Disciplines = disciplines;
                participants.Add(tmpmodel);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Hope that can give you some ideas